# can't install jekyll on Windows 7 Sp1 /Windows 10 as well

Tags: jekyll

gem install jekyll
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Windows 7 with SP1

$ gem install jekyll bundler
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0                  .6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
```

C:/tools/ruby26/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf2019                  0604-3524-k5vxhw.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0                  /ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0                  /ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR="
make failedNo such file or directory - make "DESTDIR="

Gem files will remain installed in C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/http                  _parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6                  .0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 11 seconds
1 gem installed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have installed Ruby via [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), have you installed the "devkit"?

If no, then you *may* be able to install it by running `ridk install` in your terminal.
Once you've installed the *dev tools kit*, open a fresh terminal window and try installing Jekyll again.

---

*Note:You need to have downloaded the executable containing devkit setup to install the devtools.*